# usage of 'nor' in the beginning of the sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Consider a situation where Jonh and Amanda (They are friends ) go to a restaurant. John has never been here with a girl before and Amanda has never been here with any male friends.
Now John says" I have never been here with a girl". Then Amanda says" Nor have I been here with a boy".
Is the sentence said by Amanda correct ?

Comment: That's perfectly idiomatic although so is the alternative **neither** have I been here with a boy..

Comment: You will sometimes see a scene similar to this on some older movies, where the dialogue goes along the lines of, 'I have never been here with a girl'. With the rather ungrammatical response being, 'Nor have I. Ahh! Been here with a boy that is'.

Comment: ***Nor*** (and ***neither***) require that there should be at least *some* degree of "parallelism" between the two (negated) elements being contrasted. So in *John doesn't eat meat, nor does Amanda*, the paralleled element is ***not eating meat*** (which is contextually implicit for Amanda, so it doesn't need to be explicitly repeated). That parallelism is more strained in *John doesn't eat meat, nor does Amanda eat fish*, and it breaks down completely with disconnected assertions: *John doesn't eat meat, nor does Amanda drink vodka* or *John doesn't vote, nor does Amanda wear skirts.*

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, although a bit formal sounding. Here in the US, the sentence "neither have I" is a very common response to "I have never..." statements.